# Alternative to "daydream" without the pleasant connotation

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word that means something like "daydream" or "fantasy", but without the connotation that I actually want this "imagining" to come true.

For example, something that would fit the sentence "I was on the bus today, and *fantasised* that the bus crashed and I had to decide who to save first."

*Fantasise* sounds a touch too sexual to me.

*Daydreamed* makes it sound like wishful thinking, something I hope will come true in the future.

*Imagined* is close, but doesn't have the same sense of running through the scenario in detail in my head in the way the other two do. This part is important.

Any other ideas? The sentence can be rephrased as required.

Comment: I think that among native speakers, only a severely disturbed individual would perceive any sexual connotations to *fantasized* in your example context.

Comment: As a french, I perceived it :D

Comment: Sounds like a ***daymare***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: haha, perhaps my friends are severely disturbed then :) It's more obvious when the example is something like, say, "I fantasised that the bus was boarded by hijackers who tied us all up", for example, where it might actually be someone's sexual fantasy, when I mean it more in a general "work through a scenario" way.

Comment: Fantasise doesn't sound sexual in this sense, but it does give the impression of wanting the scenario to happen.

Comment: I would say either "imagined" or "visualized", with the primary difference being verbal vs. written. In a written work, I would expect "visualized" to the be more formal term, but saying the same sentence to someone I would probably use "imagined" instead.

Comment: I would have said *visualised* except that the word suggests a very intentional action, whereas *daymare* suggests the partally involuntary nature of what I imagine you're describing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*"Visualized* is pretty neutral - could have positive or negative connotations.

Comment: From what I've heard, the situation the OP suggests is pretty common for those trained for dangerous situations, whether a martial artist, fire fighter, police officer, or secret agent. There is a constant running of "visualizations" with every potential interaction, even with passers-by, mentally preparing that person to respond to an imagined threat. As far as I know, "visualize" actually is the word used in that situation.

Comment: As it happens, a couple of activities I do regularly would fall vaguely into that category (not secret agent level, sadly). Now that I think about it I do imagine these scenarios a lot more when I've recently had to do a lot for those activities...

Answer (score 40):

> *I was on the bus today, and **envisioned** the bus crashing and deciding who to save first.*

*[envision](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envision)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]   Imagine as a future possibility; visualize:

Comment: I like this and all the other vision-based answers, but I think "visualised" fits the slightly less formal sentences I'd use in practice.

Answer (score 16):

[**contemplate**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/contemplate)

> 1. [TRANSITIVE] to consider doing something in the future
>
>    - a. to consider the possibility of something happening
>
>      *We’re not even contemplating defeat.*
>
>      *The alternative is too horrible to contemplate.*
>
>      Synonyms and related words
>
>      To imagine, or to use your imagination:*imagine, suppose, think up...*

That definition brings up another suitable word:

**suppose**

Here's a news item that uses **contemplate** in the title

[**Emergency Responders Contemplate Train Derailment Disaster Scenario**](http://www.chronline.com/news/article_047c301c-655b-11e4-9da7-8f4dc9e307cc.html)

> Personnel from multiple law enforcement and emergency response
>   agencies on Wednesday teamed up with officials with Burlington
>   Northern Santa Fe Railway and Amtrak to consider what would happen in
>   the case of a dangerous emergency train derailment. In the proposed
>   scenario, a freight train possibly transporting hazardous materials
>   and an Amtrak train derailed near the Southwest Washington
>   Fairgrounds.

That story used another suitable word:

**consider**

Comment: + I think that _contemplate_ is the term that best fits what OP's looking for,

Answer (score 8):

I think *to [muse over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/muse+over) someone or something* can convey the meaning with a neutral connotation: (MW)

> - to reflect or meditate on someone or something.
>
>   - I often muse over the possibility to go and live abroad.
>   - She is always musing over the fact she could have stayed single.

Answer (score 8):

**envisage**

- To envisage is to imagine something that does not yet exist.

**woolgather**

- form a mental image of something that is not present or that is not
  the case.

**(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/woolgather)**)**

Comment: 'Woolgather' was my first thought. e.g. "I was on the bus today, idly woolgathering: what if the bus crashed, and I had to decide who to save first?"

Answer (score 3):

**space out**

> space also    space out
>
> 2 [intransitive]  *informal*  **to stop paying attention and just look in
>   front of you without thinking, especially because you are bored or
>   have taken drugs**:
>
> http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/space_2

**zone out** 
N.Amer. *informal* fall asleep or **lose concentration or consciousness**

Comment: I think this would work better with the more generic use of *daydream*, e.g. *Johnny was daydreaming [**or spaced out**] in class and didn't remember anything the teacher said*, vs *I daydreamed [**not spaced out**] about the bus crashing and...*.

Comment: I agree with @TimS. that this can't really be substituted into the example use.

Answer (score 2):

I've got two suggestions:

One if you want to get your point across without sounding unusual:
*I was on the bus today, and I **imagined vividly** that the bus crashed, and I had to decide who to save first.*

Then this if you want to be correct, but unusual: *I was on the bus today, and I **visioned** that the bus crashed, and I had to decide who to save first.*

Oxford give these examples for *visioned*:

'Her stomach lurched as she visioned her father in that mess.'

'One chapter, darkly visioning Conrad's clinch with his dead ex-partner's mother, is remarkable and truly shocking.'

The problem I see with other people's answers are:

*envisioned* has future connotation

*visualized* = create a mental image from something non-visual

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

- **dreamed up**

> To have an imaginative, unusual or foolish idea, to invent something unreal.

- **dream of**/**about**

> To consider, think about, or give serious thought

---

You can also write :

> I was on the bus today, and tried to plan who I had to save first if the bus crashed.

The reader will easily imagine the writer state of mind.

Answer (score 1):

> Rumination

He has a lot of anxiety in his life at the moment, and he was **ruminating** about it all day at work.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to let the supporting words do the work for you.  If this is not an event that you want to happen, and the DayMare (thank you WS2 and Piers Anthony) causes your character stress, then the following phrases might carry the impact that you are looking for:
"I **couldn't help** but  ..."
"My **entire body tensed**, while my mind happily played out the most horrific scenario..."
"The scenarios played through my head.  Each **more gruesome** than the last. In each one I was presented with an impossible decision."

Hope this gives you an alternative if the correct word does not present itself.

Answer (score 1):

Premonition if it comes true:

"I was on the bus today, and had a premonition that the bus crashed and I had to decide who to save first."

Answer (score 1):

"I *pictured* the bus crashing..."

Answer (score 1):

"I was on the bus today when an unwanted image sprang to mind. I found myself deciding who to save from this crashed bus.

Answer (score 0):

> *I was on the bus today, and **ideated** the bus crashing and deciding who to save first.*

*[ideate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ideate)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT] chiefly Psychology
>   1.0 Form an idea of; imagine or conceive.
>
> 1.1 [NO OBJECT] Form ideas; think.

*[Ideator](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/ideator)*, a medical derivative of *ideate*, has strong connotations of death:

> A person experiencing suicidal ideation
>   *medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com*

Answer (score 0):

I genuinely think 'daydream' is fine in this context. It's just a particularly morbid daydream.

Comment: That's really a comment, more than it is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be called a **fabrication**, a **haunting**, or a **daymare**. All have neutral or negative connotations. Or better yet, a [contrived](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrive) daydream

Answer (score 0):

Contemplate is what I thought first came to mind or an appropriate alternative.I also thought of "deliberated" means; engage in long and careful consideration.
"she deliberated over the menu"