# Another word to describe "hallucination"

Tags: meaning

When I am alone, I tend to picture people going about their daily tasks e.g, students being engrossed in their books in a study room, or people walking across sidewalks while cars drive by, etc.

What is the word to describe this ? It is not hallucination since based on wikipedia, to hallucinate is to experience a seemingly real perception of something not actually present, typically as a result of a mental disorder or of taking drugs.

I have been googling and I can't find a word that will not put me off as mentally unstable. Would fantasize or daydream be okay ?

Comment: The following question seems similar; hopefully the answers there will be somewhat helpful: [Alternative to “daydream” without the pleasant connotation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238346)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're *[phantasms](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/phantasm)* of your imagination:

> **phantasm**, *n*.: something that you imagine you see but that is not real

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word Envision(ing) or visualize(ing).

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is not considered sufficient at StackExchange to give an answer without an explanation— *why* would you use these words? What do they mean, and what is the difference between them? What are some examples of their use? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [daydream](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daydream) [MW], used both as a noun

> a pleasant visionary usually wishful creation of the imagination

and a verb

> to think pleasant thoughts about your life or future while you are awake